# How do you properly monitor temperature in a PCB for safety?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, safety, temperature

I am building a PCB board and it is almost done. I want to add some safety features like temperature sensing for when the board gets too hot it will turn off the system. If I use only 1 temperature sensor that senses the ambient air around the board and it turns off at say +65 C or greater and -30 C or less, is that a good safety precaution for temperature? Or do you also need to measure each component individually and make sure each one individually is not heating up?

If you do need to measure each component individually could you provide an example of a part number I could use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are designing the system  you probably have a pretty good idea of what is normally (or under some kind of failure mode) generating heat, so you know whether the board will be more-or-less isothermal and where (roughly) to place a temperature sensor.

There are instances where you might want more than one sensor but typically those would more likely be situations where power devices are situated off the board.

It's also more likely to be better to mount the sensor on the board rather than in the air because that will be both more convenient for assembly and will respond faster due to lower thermal resistance.

Something like an SMT NTC thermistor mounted in proximity to parts of major concern might be one way to do it. You should allow for elevated temperature within the enclosure, maximum external ambient, maximum power dissipation, and some tolerance before deciding on the temperature setting. An allowable external ambient of (say) 60°C might result in a spot temperature on the PCB that is 30 or 40°C hotter if there is a lot of internal dissipation. Of course the parts care mostly about the junction temperature if they are semiconductors, so you can work backward from that.

I'm not sure what you expect to gain by shutting down the device at a minimum temperature unless you've identified some failure mode that occurs at low temperatures and it cannot otherwise be mitigated.

Part number requests are off-topic here, but in any case you've not provided enough information to begin doing that.

Comment: Spehro, what is a good temperature to set the system max at if part of the PCB could be 30 to 40 degrees hotter? The system will be used outdoors during the summer where it could reach 100 degrees Fahrenheit or hotter. I don't understand how I know where to set the max if part of the system could be 30 to 40 degrees hotter.

Comment: You really have to analyze what will happen. You should do that as part of the design process anyway. Generically, you'd like to prevent some kind of damage or you'd not be going to the effort of adding the sensor.